# Does the top of the function declaration and variable declaration help improve performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, declare, hoisting

I usually use JavaScript. I declare functions and variables at the top when writing code. Because there is a hoisting in JavaScript.

I saw this style in many javascript books. One day I was curious. Is this style help Javascript performance?

Does declaring functions and variables at the top help improve JavaScript performance? Is this just style guide for human?

Comment: it helps reading the code, to have all functions at top, following by the declarations and possible initializations.

Comment: It should make zero difference to performance as all declarations are processed before execution begins, it's what produces the so–called "hoisting" effect. It doesn't necessarily make readability better, otherwise there'd be no use for *let*.

Comment: This is: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/

Comment: You can call is best practices, if you are working with a team, improving performance have different topic, as all of us sharing our code, and world is more open to opensource environment then using best practices will help you to be selected for a task much easier then your own ways of coding.

Comment: @MojtabaNava I'll read it once.

Comment: @sorabh86 I'll think of best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It increases the code readability as said above, since you know the `ES6` has introduced `let` and `const`, where things are `block scoped` which is again a good practice to use while coding in Javascript,  and also more convenient

**Using var**

```
 function nodeSimplified(){
  var a =10;
  console.log(a);  // output 10
  if(true){
    var a=20;
    console.log(a); // output 20
  }
  console.log(a);  // output 20
}
```

**Using let**

```
  function nodeSimplified(){
   let a =10;
   console.log(a);  // output 10
   if(true){
     let a=20;
     console.log(a); // output 20
   }
  console.log(a);  // output 10
}
```

Comment: I realized that it has nothing to do with performance. It's for code readability..hmm. Thanks!

Comment: Reusing variable names within blocks like this totally defeats the supposed readability benefits. Omit *let* from inside the block and you change the behaviour of the code. Multiple *var* declarations have no such effect.